# (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Tags: python, snakemake

I have been trying to run this script and I am not sure why I am facing this error, can somebody help?
I have tried using the suggested methods in StackOverflow but it does not work, I have used "set +e, set -e"  as well but then the terminal is taking forever to complete the process.

```
shell.executable("/bin/bash")

import pprint
import os
import yaml
yaml.warnings({'YAMLLoadWarning': False}) # Suppress yaml "unsafe" warnings.

from globals import *

configfile: f"{cnf}pipeline_parameters.yaml"
configfile: f"{cnf}variables.yaml"

minlensize  =   config["Illumina_meta"]["minlen"]

SAMPLES     =   {}
with open(config["sample_sheet"]) as sample_sheet_file:
    SAMPLES =   yaml.load(sample_sheet_file) # SAMPLES is a dict with sample in the form sample > read number > file. E.g.: SAMPLES["sample_1"]["R1"] = "x_R1.gz"
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{p}{sample}/scaffolds.fasta",
                p= f"{datadir + scf_raw}",
                sample  =   SAMPLES),
        expand("{p}{sample}_scaffolds_ge{minlensize}nt.fasta",
                        p= f"{datadir + scf_filt}",
                        sample  =   SAMPLES,
                        minlensize  =   config["Illumina_meta"]["minlen"] )
rule De_novo_assembly:
    input:
        fastq_pR1       =   f"{datadir + cln}" + "{sample}_pR1.fq",
        fastq_pR2       =   f"{datadir + cln}" + "{sample}_pR2.fq",
        fastq_unpaired  =   f"{datadir + cln}" + "{sample}_unpaired.fq"
    output:
        all_scaffolds   =   f"{datadir + scf_raw}" + "{sample}/scaffolds.fasta",
        filt_scaffolds  =   f"{datadir + scf_filt}" + "{sample}" + f"_scaffolds_ge{minlensize}nt.fasta"
    conda:
        f"{conda_envs}de_novo_assembly.yaml"
    log:
        f"{logdir}" + "De_novo_assembly_{sample}.log"
    benchmark:
        f"{logdir + bench}" + "De_novo_assembly_{sample}.txt"
    threads: config["threads"]["De_novo_assembly"]
    params:
        max_GB_RAM          =   config["Illumina_meta"]["Spades"]["Max_gb_ram"],
        kmersizes           =   config["Illumina_meta"]["Spades"]["kmersizes"],
        minlength           =   config["Illumina_meta"]["minlen"],
        outputfoldername    =   f"{datadir + scf_raw}" + "{sample}/"
    shell:
        """
spades.py --only-assembler --meta \
-1 {input.fastq_pR1} \
-2 {input.fastq_pR2} \
-s {input.fastq_unpaired} \
-t {threads} \
-m {params.max_GB_RAM} \
-k {params.kmersizes} \
-o {params.outputfoldername} > {log} 2>&1
seqtk seq {output.all_scaffolds} 2>> {log} |\
gawk -F "_" '/^>/ {{if ($4 >= {params.minlength}) {{print $0; getline; print $0}};}}' 2>> {log} 1> {output.filt_scaffolds}
 """
```

The error is

```
Error in rule De_novo_assembly:
    jobid: 1
    output: data/scaffolds_raw/sample/scaffolds.fasta, data/scaffolds_filtered/sample_scaffolds_ge250nt.fasta
    log: logs/De_novo_assembly_sample.log (check log file(s) for error message)
    conda-env: /Users/dishaaa/Documents/Documents/internship/Jovian/.snakemake/conda/1057b0be
    shell:
        set +u
spades.py --only-assembler --meta -1 data/cleaned_fastq/sample_pR1.fq -2 data/cleaned_fastq/sample_pR2.fq -s data/cleaned_fastq/sample_unpaired.fq -t 4 -m 100 -k 21,33,55,77 -o data/scaffolds_raw/sample/ > logs/De_novo_assembly_sample.log 2>&1
seqtk seq data/scaffolds_raw/sample/scaffolds.fasta 2>> logs/De_novo_assembly_sample.log |gawk -F "_" '/^>/ {if ($4 >= 250) {print $0; getline; print $0};}' 2>> logs/De_novo_assembly_sample.log 1> data/scaffolds_filtered/sample_scaffolds_ge250nt.fasta
 set -u
 
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Does your script work without `shell.executable("/bin/bash")`? As I can see, you are using two separate scripts within a single `shell` sections: *spades* and *seqtk*. That is not correct, you need to make a single command separating them with `&&`.

Comment: The script is showing the same error without shell.executable("/bin/bash"). I am currently using macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Does the log file `logs/De_novo_assembly_sample.log` contain any useful information? Can you post its content? Also, try to execute the `spades` and the `seqtk` commands manually on the terminal and see what happens. In fact, you could put them in two separate rules so you know which one, if any, is causing trouble.

Comment: Better run snakemake with the `--printshellcmds` flag and then run each command manually. Check the result codes.